# Angular Material Design: Layout align is not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I don't know if there is something that I am missing in my Angular Material code, but I cannot seem to make the divs I have made to center and adjust to the flex that I gave them. Could this be an issue with the newest version of Angular Material? I tried the same code with an earlier version and it was working fine (Vs. 0.8.3). Or is there something that I need to add extra for the latest version of Angular Material?

**HTML**

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="center">
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <div style="background-color:#00A000;height: 40px;" flex="60">
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <div style="background-color:#004444;height: 40px;" flex="60">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <p>what's up</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Large Screen]

[image: Small Screen]

**Here is a link to to my codepen:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaNXOW

Comment: I faced similar issues. make sure you are using "angular-material#master"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular material only supports master releases.

Latest release

> `v1.0.0-rc5`

early beta versions:

> 0.11.4, 0.11.2, 0.11.1, 0.11.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.4, 0.9.0, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.1, 0.6

[Plunker using v1.0.0-rc5](http://plnkr.co/edit/hzeEXT?p=preview)

Comment: I changed the libraries and am still facing the same issue. I am using meteorjs so I am using a master pull from atmosphere to add angular-material to my packages. I added a couple screenshots of my browser to show how it is looking in my app.

Comment: I just checked the Official angular Github account and they use the cdn that I was using. So I am unsure what you are meaning. I am using the same cdn as mentioned in Angular Material's official repo

Comment: I ran your code on local it works .In bower I used "angular-material": "angular-material#master"  ...i will add plunker in few minutes